# Big difference in CV accuracy and overall training accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

```
#some imports
.......
.......

acctrain=[]
acctest=[]
roctrain=[]
roctest=[]
specifitylist=[]
specifity1list=[]
sensitivitylist=[]
sensitivity1list=[]

danesas=pd.read_csv('danesasowe.csv',delimiter=';',decimal=',')
danesas['datazalozenia'] = pd.to_datetime(danesas['datazalozenia'],format='%d.%m.%Y')
danesas['dataurodzenia'] = pd.to_datetime(danesas['dataurodzenia'],format='%d.%m.%Y')
danesas['datapozyczki'] = pd.to_datetime(danesas['datapozyczki'],format='%d.%m.%Y')
X=danesas.drop(['account_id','datazalozenia','dataurodzenia','datazalozenia','datapozyczki','status','disp_id','typkarty','Czy_problemy','duration','payments','balance'],axis=1)
y=danesas['Czy_problemy']
kolumnyX=["platnosci","wielkosckredytu","ileremittancetoanotherbank","ilewithdraw","ilecollectionfromanotherbank","iletransakcji","staz_pozyczka","ilecreditcardwithdrawal","A14","A7","POM1","A9","A11","A16","A15","A4","czastrwaniakredytu","A12","plec","ilecreditincash","A6","A13","stan_konta_przydzielanie_kredytu","ilecredit","A8","POM2","A5","wiek_pozyczka","A10"]
A=X[["platnosci","wielkosckredytu","ileremittancetoanotherbank","ilewithdraw","ilecollectionfromanotherbank"]]
neg, pos = np.bincount(y)
print("Neg:",neg,"Pos:",pos)

for i in range(100):
    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(A,y,test_size=0.2)
    sc=StandardScaler()
    X_train=sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test=sc.transform(X_test)
    sample_weights = np.zeros(len(y_train))
    sample_weights[y_train == 0] = 1
    sample_weights[y_train == 1] = 9.5
    clf=GradientBoostingClassifier(loss='deviance',n_estimators=5,learning_rate=0.3)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train,sample_weight=sample_weights)   
    y_pred=clf.predict(X_train)
    y_pred


    scores = cross_val_score(clf, A, y, cv=5)
    

    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred).ravel()
    specificity = tn / (tn+fp)
    sensitivity=tp/(tp+fn)
    specificity

    y_pred1=clf.predict(X_test)
    y_pred1
    print("CV ACC:",scores)
    print("Accuracy test:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred1))
    
    tn1, fp1, fn1, tp1 = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred1).ravel()
    specificity1 = tn1 / (tn1+fp1) # True negative rate
    sensitivity1=tp1/(tp1+fn1) #True positive rate
    sensitivity1

    #### FUNKCJA ROC ####
    acctrain.append(scores.mean())
    acctest.append(scores1.mean())
    roctest.append(roc_auc_score(y_test,y_pred1))
    roctrain.append(roc_auc_score(y_train,y_pred))

    specifitylist.append(specificity)
    specifity1list.append(specificity1)
    sensitivitylist.append(sensitivity)
    sensitivity1list.append(sensitivity1)

print("ACCTRAIN/ACCTEST/ROCTRAIN/ROCTEST")
print(np.mean(acctrain),np.mean(acctest),np.mean(roctrain),np.mean(roctest))
print("SPECIFITYTRAIN/SPECIFITYTEST/SENSITIVITYTRAIN/SENSITIVITYTEST")
print(np.mean(specifitylist),np.mean(specifity1list),np.mean(sensitivitylist),np.mean(sensitivity1list))
print()
```

I know that code doesn't look decent, as it's only for my learning however I encountered a big problem for me. I understand how cross-validation accuracy works - that it splits my data set into 5 portions in this case and tests the model on each of 5 times separately each time, so exactly how I created my model by splitting 20% of data for training, but it is done 5 times.

However, whenever I do that, the score is much higher on CV than on normal accuracy from model. For example:

[image]

I don't know whether I am doing something wrong code-wise or if Ijust don't understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Your cross validation scores (`CV ACC`) are the scores on the entire dataset since you call

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf, A, y, cv=5)
```

But your model was trained on 80% of that data, thus it is only natural that it performs better there than on the test set (`Accuracy test`), which it has not "seen" at all. I would advise to instead apply cross validation on the training set only:

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
```

Comment: Yeah yeah, i noticed it just now, but I kinda know why the values are different now - it's because of sample_weights, when I take them out the values are reasonably close to each other.

How do I pass sample_weights in cv fold or how hsould I perform it on the model?